# Pytables HDF5 ImportError cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, ubuntu, ipython, hdf5, pytables

I am getting the following error when importing PyTables in Ubuntu 13.04 in IPython:

```
In [1]: from tables import *
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-4c3ea368be2a> in <module>()
----> 1 from tables import *

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tables/__init__.py in <module>()
     80 
     81 # Necessary imports to get versions stored on the cython extension
---> 82 from tables.utilsextension import (get_pytables_version, get_hdf5_version,
     83     getPyTablesVersion, getHDF5Version)  # Pending Deprecation!
     84 

ImportError: libhdf5.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have already taken the following actions:

- Set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH environment variables correctly and verified they are pointing to the correct path by echoing their values.
- Ensured that the file libhdf5.so.8 is available in the path
- Started a new terminal
- In the terminal I have executed source /etc/environment and set the variables in those files as well.
- Ran ipython command to start ipython console

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the `pytables` package is compiled against `libhdf5.so.8` and currently in the ubuntu repository you only have [libhdf5-7](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libs/libhdf5-7) :( Also, nothing in the [updates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring-updates/libs/) :(

Ubuntu repository for 13.04 is full of unsatisfied dependencies :( I really don't know what happened to Ubuntu, but the current state is terrible. At the moment, if you install it, you cannot even install g++. :-/

I suggest you install [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) or [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/). They are both standalone binary distribution of Python that have all the scientific libraries precompiled for you, so you wont need any other dependency library. They ship the whole thing.

I ended up using Anaconda cause their package manager (`conda`) is pretty nifty.